# Can I use a matrix as index for my for loop?

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have nest for loops, and one of them I use a matrix as index. Is that acceptable? I am getting unreasonable output.

for example:

```
s=linspace(1,3,20)
d=linspace(1,3,20)

for i=1:20
 for j=1:20
  c(i,j)= s(i)+d(j)+1
k=1:c(i,j)
b(k)=2*s(i)./d(j)
```

Comment: What's "unreasonable"? Also, `c(i,j)` typically won't be an integer, which you might want it to be to do `k=1:c(i,j);`, but you're not even using `k` anyway. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is my question. Can       k=1:c(i,j) be an index in this case?

Comment: Anything that's a non-zero positive integer can be an index. The question is are you getting what you expect in `k`? If `c(i,j)` isn't an integer, then `k=1:c(i,j);` is effectively the same as `k=1:floor(c(i,j));`. And I don't know what you intend to index so I don't know if its values are appropriate.